# Telegram bot working with editable data

Tags: telegram-bot

I was wondering which way is the best to implement the following in telegram bot:
some catalog that containts some type of items with descriptions.

For example, 
Types - phones, cars, laptops.
Items - in phones: iphone, samsung, LG
In cars: BMW, Nissan
In laptops: lenovo, MSI, Dell.

Each of them has a description. I want a user to navigate through buttons, I already know how to add buttons with pre-written categories, but I want it to make editable not only through IDE but only through some commands in my bot.

Overall my bot will perform the following: a user enters and writes /start,
here he receives three buttons - phones, cars, laptops then, let's imagine, he clicks phones.
Now he has iphone, samsung, LG and back button.
Then he clicks iphone and now he gets an image with a description.
Then clicks samsung and gets another image w/ description, etc.

I want all this to be saveable and readable from a file or database so that it was easy for another people to edit in future.
Which way should I go? Should I implement some graph? Or just an input.txt files with categories and names? Or should I go harder w/ MySQL database? And how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer mysql. create a row for each category in a table called `categories`. when you want to show the categories just iterate over the table and show each row as a button in your keyboard.

and for each item in each category insert a row in table called `items` with a field or fields storing its category.

when a user select a category you will just select rows from `items` where category = something